# Xcode how to implement next keyboard button? (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard

I'm doing custom keyboard thing on Xcode using swift.

My problem is on KeyboardViewController.swift file.
I have no idea how to use next keyboard button :e
wanted to connect `@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!` to the button that i created but it is not working ..

Comment: It's default button. I don't think you can do it.

Comment: can't i use it as globe botton(change keyboard)?

Answer (score 3):

When your "Next Keyboard" button tapped, call

```
advanceToNextInputMode()
```

in your `KeyboardViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function to achieve this but with the iphone keyboard. Maybe it could help

```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    let nextTage=textField.tag+1;
    // Try to find next responder
    let nextResponder=textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTage) as UIResponder!
    if (nextResponder != nil){
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        nextResponder?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else
    {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return false // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}
```